# Rect - change the state of a property of an array mapper onclick (in functional no class)

Tags: reactjs

[image]I JSON data receive in function params , the data are mapped and display (media table). Each media contains a number of likes (ex: 88). Each time a user clicks on the like it must increase by 1 the value.

Do you have an idea, I would like to do it functionally (**no class**), Thx.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import _ from 'lodash';

//Data receive in params
const medias = [{
    "id": 623534343,
    "like": 88,
    "date": "2019-02-03"
    }, {
    "id": 625025343,
    "like": 85,
    "date": "2019-04-03"
    }, {
    "id": 2525345343,
    "like": 34,
    "date": "2019-04-05"
}];
    
const Test = ({ medias }) => {
    
    //const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    
    const handleLike = (id) => {  
        //???
    }

    return (
        <>
        {medias.map((media, index) => {
            return (
                <>
                <div key={`galerie-${index}`}>
                    <p>{media.like}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => handleLike(media.id)}></button>
                </div>
                </>
            )
        })}
        </>
    );
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: `medias` needs to be part of *some* component's state, then you can update *that*. I see it is passed as a prop, so you'll need to pass an update callback as well.

Comment: Thx i understand that it must be part of the state of the component, but i need a another way, by passing in parameter the data ? (to avoid a call to an API). How to do a callback as well please ?

Comment: Well, presumably `medias` would be in the state of *some* ancestor component. Pass a callback function to update state, along with the state, to this `Test` component. The function you need to pass is essentially the `handleLike` function from the snippet. Also, React props are basically read-only, you can't update them from the child. I'm really asking to see what and where `medias` resides and is passed as a prop.

Comment: Indeed the `medias` should not be transmitted but reside directly in the `Test` component! Thank you, often by asking questions we find an answer ... Interesting all the same the update callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to add a system of like incrementation.
Maybe it can help someone

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-fire-mbw7i?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";

const Test = ({ id }) => {
  const [medias, setMedias] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMedias();
  }, []);

  //Get the medias by ID from API
  const fetchMedias = async () => {
    //const response = await fetch(`api/.../${id}/medias`);
    //const data = await response.json();

    //Data normally received from API
    let mediaJsonExemple = [
      { id: 342550, like: 62, date: "2019-02-07" },
      { id: 8520927, like: 11, date: "2019-03-03" },
      { id: 9025895, like: 72, date: "2019-04-03" }
    ];
    setMedias(_.orderBy(mediaJsonExemple, "date"));
  };

  const handleLike = (id) => {
    const newMedias = [...medias];

    const mediasUntouched = newMedias.filter((m) => m.id !== id);
    const mediaToUpdate = _.find(newMedias, { id });
    mediaToUpdate.like++;

    mediasUntouched.push(mediaToUpdate);
    const sortedMedia = _.orderBy(mediasUntouched, "date");

    setMedias(sortedMedia);
  };

  let totalLikes = _.sumBy(medias, "like");

  return (
    <>
      <p>Total likes = {totalLikes}</p>

      {medias.map((media, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div>
              <p>{media.like}</p>
              <button onClick={() => handleLike(media.id)}>ADD</button>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
export default Test;
```